# Getting the 401 Unauthorized while setting User permissions on fastAPI delete method

Tags: python, fastapi

I am trying to set delete permissions using matching current_user.id  and owner_id after applying oAuth2. When i
`print Item.owner_id ==  current_user.id` it shows the correct ids of both showing that the owner and the current user are the same person. So i created a new user and gave it superuser permissions using only this permission `current_user.is_superuser`  , it worked but the feature is strictly for admins so i need the `Item.owner_id ==  current_user.id`  to work.

Here is the route i am trying to implement:

```
@router.delete("/delete/{id}")
def delete_item(id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db), current_user: User = Depends(get_current_user_from_token)):
    item = retrieve_item(id=id, db=db)
    if not item:
        return HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail=f"Item with id {id} not found")
    print(item.owner_id, current_user.id, current_user.is_superuser)
    if item.owner_id == current_user or current_user.is_superuser:
        delete_item_by_id(id=id, db=db, owner_id=current_user.id)
        return {"msg": "Successfully deleted item."}
    raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, detail=f"Not permitted")
```

Here is the create route:

```
@router.post("/create-item/", response_model=Item)
def create_item(item: CreateItem, db: Session = Depends(get_db), current_user: Vendor = Depends(get_current_user_from_token)):
    item = create_new_item(item=item, db=db, owner_id=current_user.id)
    return item
```

Here is my function:

```
def delete_item_by_id(id: int, db: Session, owner_id):
    existing_item = db.query(Item).filter(Item.id == id)
    if not existing_item.first():
        return 0
    existing_item.delete(synchronize_session=False)

    db.commit()
    return 1
```

The Item class:

```
class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    price: int


    class Config():
        orm_mode = True
```

The User class:

```
class User(BaseModel):
    username: str
    email: EmailStr
    is_active: bool

    class Config():
        orm_mode = True
```

Here is the Item DB Base:

```
class Item(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    price = (Column(Integer, nullable=False))

    is_active = Column(Boolean(), default=True)
    owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id")
                      )  # watch for this user.id
    owner = relationship("User", back_populates="item")
```

Here is the User DB Base:

```
class User(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    username = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = Column(String, nullable=False, index=True)
    hashed_password = (Column(String, nullable=False))
    is_active = Column(Boolean(), default=True)
    is_superuser = Column(Boolean(), default=False)
    item = relationship("Item", back_populates="owner")
```

Comment: Is it missing the `.id`? `if item.owner_id == current_user`

Comment: Exactly i was missing the ```.id```. Thanks can't believe i missed that. I've been having this issue for two days. Thanks @drum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue lies with your if condition where you are comparing `item.owner_id == current_user`. you should be comparing `item.owner == current_user` or `item.owner_id == current_user.id`

Comment: ```item.owner_id == current_user.id``` works. I appreciate.